# leftJoinF in Opaleye and IfPP

Tags: haskell, opaleye

I want to use a `LEFT JOIN` to fetch products and their (optional) attributes.
I have types like:

```
type ProductPGR = ProductPoly (Column (PGID Product)) (Column PGText)
type ProductAttributePGR = ProductAttributePoly (Column (PGID ProductAttribute)) (Column (PGID Product)) (Column PGInt4)
```

My intention was to use:

```
  (p :: ProductPGR, pa :: Maybe ProductAttributePGR) <- leftJoinF
    (\p' pa' -> (p', Just pa'))
    (\p'     -> (p', Nothing))
    (\p' pa' -> productId p' .== paProductId pa')
    productQuery
    productAttributeQuery -< ()
```

This doesn't compile because:

```
No instance for (Default
                     IfPP
                     (Maybe
                        (ProductAttributePoly
                           (Column (PGID ProductAttribute))
                           (Column (PGID Product))
                           (Column PGInt4))))
                     (Maybe
                        (ProductAttributePoly
                           (Column (PGID ProductAttribute))
                           (Column (PGID Product))
                           (Column PGInt4))))
arising from a use of ‘leftJoinF’
```

Am I really supposed to define this instance? What is it for and how would I do that?

Or if I'm not supposed to use `Maybe`, what else would I do?

Comment: What is the SQL interpretation of the `Maybe` type? If you would like to use `Maybe` in the generated SQL, you must define and implement such an interpretation. But you should not write any instances; you need functions `_Nothing :: Column (Maybe a)` and `_Just :: Column a -> Column (Maybe a)` (and probably a destructor - `caseMaybe :: Column b -> (Column a -> Column b) -> Column (Maybe a) -> b`)

Comment: `Nothing :: Maybe ProductAttributePGR` was supposed to mean that all the relevant columns are null, but from your comment and from [here](http://haskell.vacationlabs.com/en/latest/docs/opaleye/basic-db-mapping.html#different-types-for-read-write-again) it seems that `Maybe` has no business being there, instead all the columns on the right side of the join have to be `Nullable`. I thought that `leftJoinF` would help me get around that, but apparently that's not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return a `Maybe` out of a functional join.  Functional join allows you to avoid `Nullable` in the sense that it hides the `IS NULL` check from you.  It doesn't allow you to "lift the nullability" onto the Haskell side.